# BigQuery job status logic

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using this logic in order to catch BigQuery jobs 
is success or not but sometimes i'm successful job id even due the job run 
query but did't insert rows.

it's happen mainly with queries to table.

i used the code that i saw in google document and little bit add some logs for me.

it will be great if someone can tell me what i'm doing wrong.

def _wait_for_response(self, bq_api, insert_response, max_wait_time=3600):
        """get bigQuery job status. wait for DONE and check for errors.
        if errors exist - raise an exception"""

```
    start_time = time.time()
    logstr.info(current_module='bq_session',
                current_func='_wait_for_response')

    # sleep interval between retries
    # first, try 8 times every 1 second, then double sleep time until
    # 30 seconds (and stay on 30 until max_wait_time is reached)
    sleep = itertools.chain(itertools.repeat(1, 8), xrange(2, 30, 3),
                            itertools.repeat(30))

    while time.time() - start_time < max_wait_time:

        try:
            job = bq_api.jobs().get(
                projectId=insert_response['jobReference']['projectId'],
                jobId=insert_response['jobReference']['jobId']).execute()

            # on job end
            if job['status']['state'] == 'DONE':
                # if job failed raise error(s)
                if 'errors' in job['status'].keys() and\
                        job['status']['errors']:
                    raise Exception(','.join(
                        [err['message']
                         for err in job['status']['errors']]))
                else:
                    return job

        except apiclient.errors.HttpError, error:
            status = int(error.resp.get('status', 0))
            if status >= 500:
                pass
              # raise Exception(
              #     global_messages.BQ_SERVER_ERROR.format(err=error))
            elif status == 404:
              raise Exception(
                  global_messages.BQ_JOB_NOT_FOUND.format(
                      jobid=insert_response['jobReference']['jobId']))
            else:
              raise Exception(
                  global_messages.BQ_ERROR_GETTING_JOB_STATUS.format(
                                                                err=error))

        time.sleep(sleep.next())

    raise Exception(global_messages.BQ_TIMEOUT.format(
                        time=max_wait_time,
                        jobid=insert_response['jobReference']['jobId']))
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem that you are seeing.

Comment: The way I know if my job suceesully run or not its according to the script I add. Sometimes I see that job didn't load data to my tables even due I got status done with no errors. When I sent the job id to google support they answered that my job fails due to server error(internal error) and I should catch this error. I want to know why I didn't catch it by the script logic that I add.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of your script cause control to fall through if the status is greater than 500.

```
if status >= 500:
    pass
    # raise Exception(
    #     global_messages.BQ_SERVER_ERROR.format(err=error))
```

That could be preventing you from seeing the expected exception.

Comment: Its true. I did it according to google best practice, otherwise my jobs faields every hour due to internal warnings that are not critical.